# Index within a triangular grid

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the complete set of integer pairs ($a,b$) with the following constraints:

- $a \geq 0$, $b \geq 0$
- $a<n$, $b<n$
- $a<b$

The count of pairs will equal $(n)(n-1)/2$

If *n=5*, there would be ten pairs.

I am declaring the index value to be *p*.

```
| p     |  a,b  |
|-------|-------|
| 0     |  0,1  |
| 1     |  0,2  |
| 2     |  0,3  |
| 3     |  0,4  |
| 4     |  1,2  |
| 5     |  1,3  |
| 6     |  1,4  |
| 7     |  2,3  |
| 8     |  2,4  |
| 9     |  3,4  |
```

This can be intuitively laid out as a triangle, with *a* numbering each row, *b* numbering each column, and *p* being the value in each cell.

```
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
  +---+---+---+---+
0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
1 |   | 4 | 5 | 6 |
2 |   |   | 7 | 8 |
3 |   |   |   | 9 |
```

There are two questions that I'm stumped on:

- Given *n* and an index value *p*, is there a formula to determine the values of *a* and *b*?
- Given *n*, *a* and *b*, can I determine the index *p*?

Comment: I suspect that both my question title and the tag I used are inappropriate. If somebody would like to edit this, please go ahead.

Comment: What is p? - you did not define it.

Comment: It is not clear given a, b - for every n all (a, b) are determined by your discussion.

Comment: @Moti - I'm calling the index `p`. I'll add that to my table.

Comment: First question: I think it is possible, because $p$ takes different value for different pairs $(a,b).$

Comment: p, according to your discussion, is calculated as n(n-1)/2. (a, b) are all the ordered pairs - so what do you want to calculate? all the binary values less than n without the 0 at the front, determine your "pyramid".